# transforming single dimension dataframe into form of tables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a **dataframe** with four records:

```
Name: Bob

College Name:Boston

Name:Ready

College Name:IIT KGP
```

I want to transform that into form with a table that has two columns in python like:

```
Name  College 

Boob  Boston

Ready IIT
```

The separator should be ":".

Comment: Can you explain a little better your data frame?  How do you know `Bob` and `Boston` have to be in same row?

Comment: @rafaelC,My input is a dataframe, which has index and values and values further concatenated with ":". like Name: Bob and in the next row there is a college detail of Bob (college: MIT). I have thousands of records and I want it to convert into a table. Like Name and college will be my fields and values under that would be my records. In input file name get repeated after college like ( Name,college,Name,College,Name,College) . So basically I want to transpose it with unique fileds ( Name and college ) and want to put all the correspondings values below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values of column by first `:`, add counter by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df['col'].str.split(':', expand=True, n=1)
df.columns = ['a','b']
df1 = (df.set_index(['a',df.groupby('a').cumcount()])['b']
       .unstack()
       .T
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reindex(columns=df['a'].unique()))

print (df1)
    Name College Name
0    Bob       Boston
1  Ready      IIT KGP
```